# Composing slices of slices

Tags: ruby, slice

I've been thinking about this problem for a couple of days now and I can't find an elegant solution for the life of me.

In my app I have a `Text` class which is just a wrapper around `String`:

```
class Text < Struct.new(:string, :style)
  def [](start, len)
    Text.new(string[start, len], style)
  end

  def length
    string.length
  end

  def to_s
   case style
   when :bold then "**" + string + "**"
   when :italic then "_" + string +"_"
   else string
   end
  end

  def inspect
    "<[#{style}] #{string}>"
  end
end
```

I also have a `Line` class that basically is an array of Text objects:

```
class Line < Struct.new(:texts)
  def [](start, len)
    # TODO Should return a new Line object.
  end

  def length
    texts.map(&:length).reduce(&:+)
  end

  def to_s
    texts.map(&:to_s).join
  end

  def inspect
    texts.map(&:inspect).join(" ")
  end
end
```

The question is, how can I implement `#[]` in `Line` so that it returns a new `Line` object which "correctly" slices the contained `Text` objects?

The idea is to imitate the slicing behavior of `String`. For example:

```
line = Line.new([Text.new("abcdef", :bold), Text.new("ghijkl", :default)])
puts line[0, 2]  # => **ab**
p    line[0, 2]  # => "<[:bold] ab>"
puts line[3, 6]  # => **def**ghi
p    line[3, 6]  # => "<[:bold] def> <[:default] ghi>"
```

Keep in mind that the length of a `Text` object is the length of its `string` member:

```
a = Text.new("abc", :bold)
puts a  # => **abc**
puts a.length  # => 3
```

And the length of a `Line`object is just the sum of the lengths of its `texts`:

```
line = Line.new([Text.new("abcdef", :bold), Text.new("ghijkl", :default)])
puts line.length  # => 12
```

Everything I've tried involves an stupid amount of complicated conditionals and convoluted temporary variables, and I feel there's a simpler solution lurking underneath it all.

Comment: I'm probably missing something obvious but could you explain some more about the desired return values of `line[0, 2]` and `line[3, 6]`, and maybe give some more examples? Is the `[]` method supposed to return a string? What are the `*`s in the output? And why does `line[0, 2]` only give characters from `FooFoo` while `line[3, 6]` gives characters from `FooFoo` and `BarBar`?

Comment: As I said, `#[]` shoud return a new Line object.

I omitted the `#to_s` implementation in `Text` because its not relevant, but it could, as in the example, return a string containing some kind of markdown, I chose `*` to represent the `:bold` attribute.

Comment: OK, I see about returning the `Line` object (I missed that) but I still don't understand. Why wouldn't `line[0, 2]` give `*Fo*Ba`?

Comment: It will help if you can improve your example code. I suggest you edit your post. Replace `FooFoo` with `abcdef`, and `BarBar` with `ghijkl`, so we can see the output using unique characters. Write the Line `[]` method signature, such as `def [](start, len)`. Write the Text `to_s` method so we can see where the `*` characters are coming from.

Comment: @joelparkerhenderson I've edited to be more verbose and make the example code clearer, I think. Let me know if its easier to understand.

Comment: @herrecito Much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a snippet that may help you:

```
class Line

  def pos_to_index_and_offset(pos)
    raise ArgumentError if !texts or texts.empty?
    index = 0
    offset = pos
    while offset >= (size = texts[index].length)
      offset -= size
      index += 1
      raise ArgumentError if index > texts.length
    end
    return [index, offset]
  end

end
```

Comment: Well that got me `#[]` working. It isn't the most beautiful piece of code in the world but should do the trick. Thanks for your answer.